# asp.net button not firing within jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to click the ASP.net button within a jQuery dialog box but it's not firing.

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
  <label >Item Name</label>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemNames" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-new"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemNames2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-new"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSaveChild" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("[id*=btnItemType]").live("click", function () {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
          title: "Item Asset Details",
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          buttons: {
              Close: function () {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
          },
          modal: true
      });
      return false;
  });        
</script>
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? Did you check the console log in browser.

Comment: no i did't...i just added links :<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Live event is deprecated in jquery 1.7 use the [ON](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event to trigger the click event for the button control.

Comment: Removed unnecessary words.